# Install libmpfr-dev 4.10+ with apt

Tags: linux-mint, apt

Heyo all,

I've created a from-scratch linux distribution, or more specifically just the bootstrapper. This works flawlessly, but gcc wants MPFR 4.10+ on your system do download. Now this is fine for me, because Portage has MPFR 4.10+. But recently an awesome friend has donated his server, so I could ssh into and build from there (he has 64 cores!). The thing is, this server runs on Mint. Now I'm getting an error because to build gcc, I need mpfr 4.10+, while apt installs a lower version. As someone who hasn't worked with apt a lot, is there a way to install libmpfr 4.10+ through apt?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mean mpfr 4.1.0, not 4.10.

As the latest version in the repos is 4.1.0, you'll have to build it from the source code which you can get here: https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr-4.1.0.tar.gz

Make sure that you have libgmp-dev installed beforehand and if you don't:

```
apt-get install libgmp-dev
```

Afterwards, add it to your environment:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mpfr/4.1.0/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```